# Having trouble replicating an effect

Tags: jquery, css

A client of mine wants a similar effect to the homepage of creative agency [Red](http://ff0000.com/) where, on page load, the blocks appear to scroll upwards at slightly different times.

I'm stumped as to how this was achieved. Can anyone shed any light on it for me?

Comment: Have a look at the source code?

Comment: @Reeno It didn't help much, I couldn't tell what related to what

Comment: The RED site is really impressive, but with 100+ creative geeks in one place, this is what you can accomplish.  The sroll-upward effect appears to be based on CSS transitions.  You would need to start digging through the CSS to reverse engineer the technique.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle i did that works kind of that way

http://jsfiddle.net/T4RHp/1/

keep in mind that opacity might have some issues with IE

EDIT: The setTimeout() is not needed, i just put it there to get some delay when running the script

code:

```
var timeArray = [200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800];

setTimeout( function() {

    $('.box').each( function ()
    {
        var intVal = Math.floor((Math.random()*12));
        $(this).animate({ top: 0, opacity: 1 }, timeArray[ intVal ]);   
    });

}, 500);
```

css:

```
.box 
{
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    float: left;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```